# WORD 2010 Macro for Editing Headers & Footers

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have only basic VBA experince and my prior Macro experence was primarily with WORD 2003.  Recording Macros used to take GoToFooter (or Edit Footer) Menu Commands and allow subsequent editing.  In WORD 2010, this (and many other) commands do not "record" to the Macro (yet when in Record mode, I do get into Edit Footer function).

A research of various VBS options shows several ways to create Footers and to make global Footer setting changes within Macro.  However If I simply want to Revise the Company name within the Footer (for example), I can find no way to do this within a Macro subroutine.

This subroutine is one that I would call from the Main Macro that is stepping through each file in a Folder (& subfolders).  I have the main Macro functioning.

Does WORD 2010 Macro-VBA preclude simple Edit-Footer function?

Thanks in advance

So, thanks to Issun, here is my solution:

```
`
Sub Sub_FTR_0()
'
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
 'REM: INSERT Code from RECORD MACRO recorded when editing one Footer correctly
    Selection. [[xxx]], etc.

If i = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count Then GoTo Line1

    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter

Line1:
Next

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub
`
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a way you can access the headers/footers via VBA. As you can see, it's rather complicated syntax to get to something so simple :p there

```
Sub EditHeadersAndFooters()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(i)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Foo"
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Bar"
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Here is a link to example code on how to change the headers in every file in a folder. It takes a different approach and I have never tried it, but for your reference: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=45

Comment: Thanks!! 
I had seen this syntax and presumed that it essentially completely replaces the Header &/or Footer with "FUBAR" material [ :) ] ... still not allowing me to pick & choose my edits withint he Footer (like replacing the first 3 words or the last word, etc).  
So each file has a unique page numbering scheme (not Field-Coded) so complete replacement is not an option I have envisoned a work-around for.

Comment: THANKS (again). A combination of your suggestion and the link provided lead me to me fix. Here is the "simple" routine to allow me to get into the Footer(s) and edit portions.

Sub Sub_FTR_0()
'
' Sub_FTR_0 Macro

  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter
For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
 '(REM) Add: FOOTER EDIT Selection.[cmds]
If i = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count Then GoTo Line1
  ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter
Line1:
Next
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End Sub

Comment: `code`
Sub Sub_FTR_0()
'
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count

    '(REM) Add: FOOTER EDIT Selection.[cmds]

If i = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count Then GoTo Line1
    
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.NextHeaderFooter

Line1:
Next

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
    
End Sub
`code`

Comment: Glad it helped. Post your new code in your question so users can see your solution and if my answer worked, you can click in the check mark in the upper left of it to 'accept' it. :)

Comment: How can i set aliment?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me for all pages in the document.

word.ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Text = "Put the header here"