# Copy header content from .doc to .xlsm file

Tags: vba, header, copy, ms-word

How can I copy the header from a .doc file to some cells in a worksheet using VBA?

Here's the best I could come up with:

```
Sub extract_header()
    Const wdSeekMainDocument = 0 'this I copied from another code I found
    Const wdReplaceAll = 2 'but I have no clue if it's usefull or not, I guess not
    Const wdPrintView = 3
    Const wdSeekCurrentPageHeader = 9
    Const wdSeekCurrentPageFooter = 10
    Path = "C:\Users\guillaume.hebert\Documents\Optimisation\Table des matières\TAB-MAT3.doc" 'define the path
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Documents.Open (Path)
    With objWord.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View
        .Type = wdPrintView 'change viewing mode
        .SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader 'open the header
    End With '  now what is the commande I should use to copy the content of the header,
             ' so I can then paste in my excel worksheet, objWord.Header.Copy  ?
End Sub
```

The header contains a table as in the screenshot below:

[image]

I now get this error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for the basics of how to access the header/footer:

[WORD 2010 Macro for Editing Headers & Footers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131219/word-2010-macro-for-editing-headers-footers)

NB: This code is for Word, implemented in Word, so it will require some modifications for you.

```
Sub EditHeadersAndFooters()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    With ActiveDocument.Sections(i)
        .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Foo"
        .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = "Bar"
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

First, declare your variables! (`objWord` appears undeclared in this context) and add another variable to represent the `Document` that you open with the `.Open` statement. This will make your code more legible.

```
Sub extract_header()

Const wdSeekMainDocument = 0              'this I copied from another code I found
Const wdReplaceAll = 2                    'but I have no clue if it's usefull or not, I guess not
Const wdPrintView = 3
Const wdSeekCurrentPageHeader = 9
Const wdSeekCurrentPageFooter = 10
Path = "C:\Users\guillaume.hebert\Documents\Optimisation\Table des matières\TAB-MAT3.doc"        'define the path

Dim objWord as Object
Dim doc as Object 'Word.Document
Dim h as Object 'Word.HeaderFooter

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application") 

'## Assign to the DOCUMENT variable:
Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open(Path)

'## Get the primary header from the first section
'   Note: there may be multiple sections, you will need to figure that out on your own
Set h = doc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
h.Range.Select
objWord.Selection.Copy

'Paste the entire table to Excel
Range("A10").Select
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteSourceFormatting"



End Sub
```

At that point, I'm not sure what you need to do with it. The header can contain lots of stuff like shapes, text, etc. So what you do next depends on what you really need to extract in to the Ecxel file.

Comment: Hello David,  Thanks for answer.  I guess I'm halfway there.  the content of the header is only text placed in a table.  So what I need is to copy all the text from the Word.doc header into a specific cell of my workbook.  So how can I copy and paste this.

Comment: Please update your original question with a screenshot of the header/table (upload a picture to imgur.com and include a link in the question) and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: I've add the link, as asked.  Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I made a revision that would paste the entire table to Excel. You would need to iterate that table and and combine the string values if you want to put *all* the values in a *single* cell.

Comment: David you're my hero!  I just saw the  lines "set h..."    "h.range.select"  and objWord.selection.copy.  I've added this to the rest of the code and it work's beautifully.